# I Added a jar into my Eclipse project, but still it doesn't import

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package esta.fontend;

import java.awt.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import esta.dbConnection.ConnectionDB;

import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;// This is where i find the problem;
```

[Image Link explaining my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eodyc.png)

Comment: Have you tried this [Adding jar to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Comment: I'd really suggest to use a package manager if you can. It downloads published jars and adds them to the classpath automatically. Two popular choices are maven and gradle. Eclipse has plugins for working with both of them

Comment: So your Jar is in the referenced projects, so you should be fine. Have you just cleaning and rebuilding your project?

Comment: i tried to clean the project and rebuild it but that didn't work , i'm interested in what you said about the package manager, what do i need to do to get these plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

`rs2xml.jar` doesn't contain the needed java class.
The most probably reason is that it was built incorrectly.

As you may see it contains 'src.net.proteanit.sql' which is empty.

So to fix the problem the jar should be rebuilt

1. The package should not include 'src' prefix
2. The DbUtils class should be truly included into it.

Comment: I guess DbUtils is included in the jar, and i tried to add it in the build path but still i faced the same problem, it doesn't recognize the jar at all.

Comment: Try unpacking the jar to see its contents. Eclipse shows that the 'package' src.net.proteaint.sql is empty (by white background color). In any case the 'src' prefix is most likely also wrong.

Comment: So i deleted the src file and tried to add it to the libraries using "add an external jar", then tried to import it  " import net.proteanit.sql; ", but it didn't work either.

Comment: does Eclipse show net.proteanit.sql package as not empty? In the package explorer it should look brown similarily to org.jdom.xpath and be expandable - so that you can see its contents

Comment: Look at the jar file, the second package is what i want to import net.proteanit.sql and it is not empty it contains classes and DbUtils in one of them.

Comment: try Project - Clean to make Eclipse refresh the project