# Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver in selenium webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am trying this code but it fails

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

  public class Fijan {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:Users\\Devrepublic\\Documents\\fijan\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver");
    WebDriver driver =  new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("");
    }
```

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

```
at prac.Fijan.main(Fijan.java:12)
```

Comment: Your selenium version, driver version , browser version ?

Comment: Why do you want to cast a `ChromeDriver` to a `WebDriver`? It's obvious that this does not work, and your IDE should already tell you about it

Comment: I think you need add extension in path (.exe) may be this helps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the following jars to buildpath - selenium-java.jar, selenium-remote-driver.jar, selenium-support.jar

Eclipse:
[How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

InteliJ
[Correct way to add external jars (lib/*.jar) to an IntelliJ IDEA project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-external-jars-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project)

Comment: thanks, i added jar files in module path before, just remove it from there and again add jars in class path, it works file

Comment: glad to hear that. please accept my answer if you think it helped you.