# Convert String (http json) to Object in java (automatic)

Tags: java, json, eclipse, web-services

I'm a beginner in programming, and I need some help. Is it possible to convert an HTTP (that returns a Json) automatic call to object in java? For example it reads the request, and when I call System.out.println (obj) it already returns me an OBJECT of this request, instead of String. Is it possible? If so, could you help me ... I already did the method to call the url and return string, but I need to return OBJECT, so I can compare with HashCode and Equals.

**My code:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQXM0.png)
**output:** 
{"header":{"messageId":"02938ec7-b2c3-4131-8ecf-3ad3a8509b41"},"body":{"products"

**What I wanted: output**
Informacoes [header=Header [messageId=66d22c00-bddc-4ea7-afbd-7c7225fcb914], body=Body

Comment: Questions should be in English please.

Comment: Please add your code as text, not an an image.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand from your question, it looks like [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) might be useful. Gson is a library that allows you to convert between JSON and Java primitives/objects. Here's an example I just wrote:

```
    class BagOfPrimitives {
        private int value1 = 1;
        private String value2 = "abc";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = "{\"value1\":1,\"value2\":\"abc\"}";
        BagOfPrimitives obj = gson.fromJson(json, BagOfPrimitives.class);
    }
```

This code converts the json `{"value1":1,"value2":"abc"}` into an object of the class `BagOfPrimitives`.

To add Gson to your project, go [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.8.5/jar), click "Downloads" at the top right, and click "jar". Then follow [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse) to add the jar file to your project. Then you should be able to write `import com.google.gson.*` at the top of your class and use Gson in your java code.