# how to fix the error triggered by the use of jfoenix?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder, jfoenix

I added JFoenix to eclipse and SceneBuilder.
It works in SceneBuilder but while compling the project leads to ClassNotFoundException

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: /C:/Users/Dell/eclipse-workspace/WDP-solver/bin/application/Sample.fxml
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(Unknown Source)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:13)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$11(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(Unknown Source)
... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

The `scenebuilder` is able to find the `jphoenix` library, but your project / the java codes that you wrote cannot find the jphoenix library. That is why you are getting the `ClassNotFoundException`. So to fix this, you have to import the jar file in your project. I don't use eclipse myself, so I myself don't know how to do this. A quick google revealed this answer:

### [how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

According to this, `You can add a jar in Eclipse by right-clicking on the Project → Build Path → Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or Add External JARs and give the Jar.`
Maybe this will help. Once imported, your project should compile properly. Good luck.

Comment: in my case the jar is imported on eclipse too !! that's the problem