# Eclipse Java External jar does not Compile (but runs)

Tags: java, eclipse, import, jar, buildpath

I've to import `javax.*` in my project. So I created lib folder in my project, I put activemq-all-5.16.1.jar in it, then added it in classpath (add jar).
Now if I select a file with a main and select "Run", it runs without any problem, however I need to run multiple files at the same time, so I need to actually compile the code using `javac` and then run them by terminal.

Problem is, that when I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
sas\Sas.java:3: error: package javax does not exist
import javax.*;
^
1 error
```

File is:

```
package sas;

import javax.*;

public class Sas {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.print("SAS");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in the javax package itself that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

check out this answer it worth to read
[How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

> re install the jar file and check