# Encountered problem to perform test case when fetching data from Excel file using KeywordDriven

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Problem I'm facing is libraries are not imported like `Workbook`, `Row`, `Cell`, `HSSFWork` etc. When i try to import its not importing.

Here is link of console:  https://prnt.sc/15oajs9

```
 public class ReusableFunction {
    WebDriver driver;
    public  String [][] fetchDataFromExcel() {
        Workbook wb = null;
        String [][] data= null;
        try {
            String path = fetchprop("KEYWORD_PATH");
            File excel = new File(path);
            FileInputStream file  = new FileInputStream(excel);
            
            System.out.println(path);
            String extn = path.substring(path.indexOf(".")+ 1);
            System.out.println(extn);
            if (extn.equals("xlsx")) {
                wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            } else {
                wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
            }
            Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
            
            int rownum = sheet.getLastRowNum();
            System.out.println("Rows: " + rownum);
            
            int column = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();
            
            data  = new String [rownum][column];
            
            for (int i =0; i < rownum; i++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                for (int j =0;  j < column; j++) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    String value = cell.toString();
                    data[i][j] =  value;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                wb.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        
        return data;
    }`
```

Can anyone have idea how we can solve this problem

Comment: Does not look like a maven project, does it ?

Comment: likely your Apache poi libraries are not detected by eclipse. I would recommend you to go through this stack overflow question to import library to project
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse

and then may be copy the below import statments and try

`import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;`

Comment: @Anoop : XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type Not working, all others are working fine. Here is screenshot:  https://prnt.sc/15ohysf

Comment: @cruisepandey : I have converted it into maven butt problem is same. Here is screenshot: prnt.sc/15ohysf

Comment: @cruisepandey : Great! its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these dependency in your pom.xml file :

**poi**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**poi-oxml :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**commons-collections :**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
    <version>4.4</version>
</dependency>
```

**commons-compress :**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    <version>1.20</version>
</dependency>
```

**xmlbeans**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**dom4j**

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Build your project and then run, should work for you.