# Turn .java in .jar and implement the jar in the project

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a java project in eclipse and I have a .java file with some code for handling user password, decryption, encryption etc. and I want to turn the .java file into a .jar file and add the jar to the project, so that I can acces it, but not change it or look at the code.

I turned it into a .jar with

javac -d ./build *.java

jar cvf YourJar.jar *

and added the jar to the project but when I call the classname it doesn't give me an option to import it.

```
CryptoHandler.getSql() // <- original class name

// => err: CryptoHandler cannot be resolved
```

Comment: How did you add the jar to the project?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a jar in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse)

Comment: I adde it via the java build path -> libraries -> add external jar

Comment: @GauthamM nope sadly not

Comment: I hope you have gone through multiple answers on that question and not just the accepted answer.