# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Serializable while using ActorSystem in Java project

Tags: java, akka

I am new to java and AKKA toolkit. I have created a JAVA project and tried to include the below code

```
    package com.postgresqltutorial;

    import akka.actor.ActorSystem;

    public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("QuickStart");
      }

    }
```

I have used AKKA libs in referenced libs as akka-actor_2.12-2.6.15.jar, akka-protobuf_2.12-2.6.15.jar and akka-stream_2.12-2.6.15.jar.

And my project structure is like
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jb6b.png)

Please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you've not referenced the libraries correctly. That is why you should use a build tool such as [Maven](https://www.baeldung.com/maven). Check the referenced link to understand how it works. It handles the libraries for you, you just have to add them in the `pom.xml` file.

Example:

```xml
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_3</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.18</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is it possible to include the jars without creating the Maven project? This means I just want to go with a basic Java project.

Comment: Yes, you can. Unfortunately, I do not use eclipse but take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse