# How to add JEP library in Eclipse to validate the formula?

Tags: java, validation, jep

I have downloaded the trial version of ZEP library from http://www.singularsys.com/jep/download-trial.php and extracted it, but now i need you help to add this in the IDE (eclipse) to use it

what is the process to start using the JEP library to validate the formula.

Comment: **This question requires a specific programming problem. This question is too broad and does not focus on a particular question.** Please fix any typos, provide relevant code examples, solutions you have tried, and any additional information. **Answers that can be easily found with a Google search will be removed.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It was a simple question about how to add a library into IDE, and I got the answer.
thank you so much all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lib folder if it doesn’t exist in a project that is targeted to use jep. Drop the jar file obtained [like getting started here](http://www.singularsys.com/jep/doc/html/usage.html) into lib.

Add the jar to the Build Path like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3280353/how-to-import-a-jar-in-eclipse/3280384#3280384). The add jars option not the add external jars option