# int byte to string in java

Tags: android, sockets, arrays

**Problem**

I read first byte in my socket client to check connection:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
...
int dataInt = clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
```

**Documentation**:

> Reads a single byte from this stream and returns it as an integer in
>   the range from 0 to 255. Returns -1 if the end of the stream has been
>   reached.

after that I want to splice this byte with next input string. I convert this integer byte to characters

```
b.putInt(dataInt);
byte[] dataByte = b.array();
final String data;
```

and check it. If dataInt != -1, I have to return this croped byte into new string:

```
if(dataInt != -1)
{
    String c = new String(dataByte);
    Log.v("MSG", c);
    data = c + inToServer.readLine();
}
else
{
    data = inToServer.readLine();
}
```

Why I see in log "MSG, ������MY MESSAGE"? How to get a string correctly?

---

Upd, how I send my messages:

```
byte[] buf = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
outToServer.write(buf, 0, buf.length);
outToServer.writeBytes("\n");
outToServer.flush();
```

Comment: In Java, characters are represented as two bytes. Although your file may or may not be storing them as 1 or 2. Something to consider. Maybe your b allocation should be 1 or 2, not 4.

Comment: So, how to splice this byte and bytes in next string?

Comment: How are your characters stored? as 4 byte integer values of a char? If this is the case, you shouldnt be creating a string from the byte array directly, but casting the int value to char.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Omg, I did it.
Solution:

```
byte[] b1 = new byte[1];
int dataInt = clientSocket.getInputStream().read();
b1[0] = (byte)dataInt;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(dataInt != -1)
{
    String c = new String(dataByte, "UTF-8");
    Log.v("MSG", c);
    data = c + inToServer.readLine();
}
else
{
    data = inToServer.readLine();
}
```

Comment: No, it does not work. V/data(30887): ������msg#Leo#kokoko
E/AndroidRuntime(30887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: @Leo His answer looks pretty solid to me. +1 for more in-depth. Are you sure the byte array you recieved is complete. And not anything additional. Send a small string, and see what numbrs are in the array, before and after.

Comment: Perhaps try `new String(dataByte, "ISO-8859-1");` so you can at least see what bytes are coming back instead of the invalid unicode character ?'s

Comment: @Doomsknight Yes, I'm sure cause if I dont use clientSocket.getInputStream().read(), all my messages is complete. But so I cant't see my socket state.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so on your server side just do this with your recieved byte[] There is no need for byte buffers, or to manipulate it in any way.

```
String str = new String(recievedBytes);
```

Comment: @Leo remove your byte buffer stuff, and read it directly into the `new String(recievedBytes); ` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [IOUtils.toString](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toString%28java.io.InputStream%29) for this. It facilitates a lot of the boring and error prone input/output stream manipulation.

Here is an answer explaining [how to setup your project to use apache IO commons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769889/how-to-include-apache-commons-io-in-eclipse-java).